# I am new to IOT and am looking for some platform I can use to learn how to create IOT applications

Tags: aws

I am very new to IOT and don't have much knowledge of anything to do with it. I have spent a long time trying to learn more about it but everywhere I go to try to learn about IOT, there is always way too much assumed knowledge that I don't have. My end goal is to be able to develop applications for collecting data from IOT devices and presenting it to a client and I've decided the best way to do this is to get some practical experience. So I signed up to AWS and want to begin using the IOT service to get some idea of how its done. I want to learn how to create applications that collect data from IOT devices but I need some devices to do this with but I don't have any. Is there anywhere that allows me to may be play around with some fake devices or practice devices or something?

Comment: Can you please tell us more about your skill level. Do you have experience in embedded system programming? Do have have access to hobby electronic or starter electronic boards such as a [TIVA ARM® Cortex®-M4F Based MCU TM4C123G LaunchPad™ Evaluation Kit ](http://www.ti.com/tool/EK-TM4C123GXL) and/or [TI SimpleLink™ Bluetooth® low energy CC2650 Module BoosterPack™ Plug-in Module](http://www.ti.com/tool/BOOSTXL-CC2650MA). There are plenty of options in the market.

Comment: I dont have experience in ebedded system programming and i dont have any electronic boards but I could by a £10 device in order for me to learn. My experience is complete begginer. I dont know what any of the terms used in the field really mean or how to create any part of an IOT system. All I do know is the general idea, IOT devices are made to collect data at "the edge" (showing off one of the only terms I know lol) and then that data is sent to servers in the cloud where people can write programs that collect, analyse and present the data (which is what im eventually trying to learn to do)

Comment: In order to get where want to, I recommend getting some basic understanding of embedded programming. This link [How to Transition from “Basic” Microcontrollers to ARM Cortex? ](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/176824) has some references to help you get started. Particularly the [Embedded Systems - Shape The World: Microcontroller Input/Output](https://www.edx.org/course/embedded-systems-shape-the-world-microcontroller-inputoutput-2)

Comment: Not a direct duplicate, but very relevant is https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1425/is-there-a-big-jump-between-prototyping-on-a-pi-and-using-a-microcontroller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome. I love your question, and have marked it a favo(ur)ite. However, it will probably be closed as far too broad. If you can narrow down your requirements, you will probably get a good answer (try to avoid GIGO). Here is ***one of many*** possible paths that you could take:

> My end goal is to be able to develop applications for collecting data from IOT devices and presenting it to a client

Collect data only ([telemetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telemetry)) or also control the devices ([SCADA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCADA))?

> So I signed up to AWS

Why? Is AWS a hard requirement, to did you just associate it with IoT and think “why not”?

You certainly don't need AWS, and I would suggest starting with the simplest system you can think off and working your way into something more complicated.

What do you need?

1. Some hardware to measure something
2. A way to send the measurements to a client
3. A way to display the data to a client (presumably a human client?)

1)  The [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) is very popular and has a lot of support an tutorial; it even has [its own Stack Exchange site](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)  At less than US $10, it has WiFI, BlueTooth and GPIO pins for your sensors (you can also buy Hats with sensors to fit those pins, if you are way of soldering or even breadboards). The Raspberry Pi Zero W is the cheapest with internet connection and should be enough for any IoT project you are considering.

Having said that, I personally (and YKmH may vary), I find the Pi to be overkill, as I do not see that you need Linux. If you give more detailed requirements, we can point you at a processor. A good starter would be the ESP32, which you can pick up on AliExpress from about $7, maybe $14 with display. I also like the [STM32](https://www.raspberrypi.org/), which I am about to look into because of its support for Ada 2012, but that might be a tad esoteric for you. Consider also the [BBC Micro:bit](https://microbit.org/) which is expressly designed for leaners (they gave one to every school kid in the UK), and can be programmed in Python (as can the others I mentioned), or Ada ;-) or in a graphical language.

If you want a recommendation of ESP32, take a look at [M5stack](https://m5stack.com/) which is a modular system and allows you to easily combine (stack) devices and accessories (e.g device battery) and has a dozen or more sensors to measure many things. It is cheap (IMO) and easy to get to grips with, and I bought the lot, just to have a play.  Once bonus is that you don't need to do any soldering or breadboarding (although you can); everything is plug 'n' play. You might be interested in [the wrist “wearable”](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32994893797.html?spm=a2g1y.12024536.productList_12432753.pic_2), which looks pretty cool & which I am using to track employees.  See below for image

2)  So, now you have programmed your device to read some sensor data, and want a way to send it to a server. There an numerous ways to do this, but personally I see it as a choice between developing a RESTful HTTP API, or using something FOSS and off the shelf.
For the latter, there are a few options, but [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/) is very popular & well documented, and there are lots of examples. It is also very simple to learn.

3)  Displaying the data. Again, there is a plethora – nay, a cornucopia – of choices for reports. However, the FOSS [Node-RED](https://nodered.org/) is simple to use and very popular with good support.

You mentioned AWS, but that’s just one more thing to confuse yourself with at the start (not to say that you shouldn’t get into it later). Simpler is to run your own server, on your own PC. If you run Linux, you aleady have Apache installed. If Windows, then install something like [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) which will run an Apache server on Linux and doesn’t require much/any knowledge.

That, as I said, is just one of many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many options, but it will get you started & allow you to pick up some other skills along the way.

If you do go for ESP32, then, in addition to many great free tutorials, I personally  recommend reading   [Kolban's book on ESP32](https://leanpub.com/kolban-ESP32) and [ESP32 Programming for the Internet of Things](https://leanpub.com/esp32_IoT).
For good tutorials, look at [Random Nerd](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/)  and [Hackster](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/). As an IDE, I ***strongly*** recommend [PlatformIO](https://platformio.org/)_ over the Arduino IDE, as it supports debugging on many boards, plus lots more, and it has a great support community.

[image]

Did I miss any general advice?

I encourage others to expand on this answer. While the question is too broad to stay open, an answer would be very useful on the community wiki.

Comment: thanks for this answer, this seems to be a really good starting point. I have a few questions. "If you give more detailed requirements, we can point you at a processor. ": i dont really have any requirements, only to learn. My end goal is actually to be using wise-paas for a business application so anything that will help me learn what I need for that is useful. You also mention that you could point me to a processor, do you mean instead of the pi? and how could I use a processor on its own for collecting data?

Comment: "If you want a recommendation of ESP32" here do you mean a reccomendation for a model of the ESP32 processor?

Comment: I just meant any ESP32, as opposed to a Pi or STM32,. etc, etc, etc

Comment: "`i dont really have any requirements, only to learn`"  then you will find M5stack with PlatformIO MQTT, IDE, Apache/XAMPP and Node-RED to be an easy to use, well supported, end-top-end solution.

Comment: what is M5stack, is it like a model for the ESP32?

Comment: Yes, it is ESP32, and it has lots of modular sensors that you can "stack" together, like GPS, heat/temperature sensor, plus things like LoRa, GSM ... take a look at https://m5stack.aliexpress.com/store/3226069

Comment: oh ok nice I think i might just have to get that, so next you talk about sending the devices data to a server and gave the choice of either developing a "RESTful HTTP API" or using FOSS, keeping my end goal in mind, (creating applications for collecting analysing and presenting data for a buisness IOT system), do you think I could use FOSS or would I need to know how to develop my own RESTful HTTP API? If the latter could you please explain what a RESTful HTTP API is

Comment: You can certainly use FOSS, and MQTT has great documentation & support. If you need something custom, tehn develop your own RESTful API (see https://searchmicroservices.techtarget.com/definition/RESTful-API and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer). To get started, I would suggest MQTT; develop as little as possible, only what you must & MQTT is great for reporting sensor data. That will give you a feel for it (and those books are helpful)

Comment: ok thanks ive been spending some time checking out the ESP32 and it looks like a very good option

Comment: I am glad to here it. I have chosen it do and have bought a bunch of them. Good luck.

Comment: New MQTT lab for AWS IoT Core

http://mqttlab.iotsim.io/aws/